# Windows 10 File History

Tags: backup

Not sure if this is possible, but i was hoping that the File History versions would be restorable over the network and for all users who have access to the share.

Currently, the versions are only accessible/visible to the user who created the backup history and only when signed-in to the local machine.

example:

Share location: \server01\data

Physical Location: \Server01\d$\data

File History Location: \Server01\e$\FileHistory

User1: created the file history on Server01 locally.

User1: access the file share over the network and attempts to view the version; "There are no previous versions available"

User1: goes to pyshical location and is able to see all restorable versions.

Answer (score 0):

So from my understanding this is a feature of File History. But there's definitely ways around it. File History just stores... well files, with.. a history. OK maybe that's obvious but they're just files on the filesystem that can give you the history. I'm going to assume you're an admin (comment if not) and as I see it here are your options:

1. You could manually copy the File History folder (\Server01\e$\FileHistory) to a network share that all users can access. You could script this out and also ensure the permissions are sh**ty enough that other users can access it. If I were you, from a security perspective, I'd make a group of people that need that access and give that group access instead of just making it wide open.

That would look something like this:

```
# Define the source and destination directories
$sourceDir = "\\Server01\e$\FileHistory"
$destDir = "\\Server01\data\FileHistoryBackup"

# Define the user group that should have access
$userGroup = "YourGroupName"

# Create the destination directory if it doesn't exist
if (-Not (Test-Path $destDir)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $destDir
}

# Copy the File History folder to the network share
Copy-Item -Path $sourceDir -Destination $destDir -Recurse

# Change permissions to give the user group access
icacls $destDir /grant "$userGroup:R"
```

You could schedule this to run regularly, or even whenever there's a change in the File History store folder.

2. Does it have to be via File History? Windows has another feature called Shadow Copies that's really a backup solution but you can point it to wherever you want (including a share - in fact most of the times it's some kind of Network File System). It provides a history of files as well, though it may not have all of the same info you want. [Check it out and see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/volume-shadow-copy-service)! Just check the permissions, but my understanding is they should be accessible by default. Just to make sure you can run `icacls $destDir /grant "$userGroup:R"` to make sure whatever group can use it (if you want to make it really open just open it up to the Users group or Domain Users group).

All of that said, File History is meant to be restricted to the user for security reasons. Be careful using any of the hacks above and exposing them to others. Try to be as least permissive as possible. The history may contain secrets, sensitive info, and other stuff you might not want shared so be sure to carefully configure it.

Edit: The script is just an example from my understanding of your source and destination directories/shares. Please check the paths and such to make sure!

Comment: Thanks for the input Alex, that is correct I am an Admin. I have already configured Security Groups to manage the permissions and I am operating in a Window AD domain.

I was hoping to configure on the host system itself to maintain the versioning (for security that way the data stays on that machine, keeps my audits clean) but was hoping to empower my users to self manage by using the "right click" context menu to "restore Previous Versions"